# How to handle division of a large number by a small number in Python

Tags: python, integer-division

I've recently discovered that Python gives me inaccurate results when I try to divide a number with 17 or more digits by a single digit divisor.

For example, 77777777777777777/7 returns the value 11111111111111112 (instead of 11111111111111111 as it should). Same issue with 88888888888888888/8. If I go to even larger numbers the problem becomes more pronounced (i.e. deviates even more from the correct value).

I have observed this issue on different platforms (in Mu on Windows as well as Pydroid3 on android).

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: You want to use integer division - `//` instead of `/`.  Floats simply don't have any more precision that about 16 digits.

Comment: To add to this, I believe using floating-point division `/` causes Python to use an intermediate limited-precision floating point representation when carrying out the calculation, which is then cast back to an `int` at the end. `//` forces Python to use `int`s the whole way through. Note also how passing the intepreter `77777777777777777/7` gives `1.1111111111111112e+16` (scientific notation), whereas `77777777777777777//7` gives `11111111111111111` (integer notation).

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. Using // does indeed work very well for my intended use. I did notice that the answer came back in scientific notation, but my solution to that was 'print(int(x))'. Are there any known limitations to how large integers can be handled in integer division?